# How to use animated jQuery Counter with asp.net updatepanel?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, updatepanel

I want to use an animated jQuery counter that refreshes (to increase value) using an ASP.net UpdatePanel.

In this website: http://www.mywot.com/
You should be able to see an animated counter that keeps refreshing increasing value, and it is exactly the one I need.

anyone have the trick?!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do it because updatepanel is refreshing everything inside it, so if you have some javascript code inside panel it will bi reseted after user makes some action inside update panel